# Too many decimals after addition

Tags: c#

I would like to add 0.01 to 36.01 and get 36.02 as the result
But below code returns 36.019999999999994.

```
Double d = 36.01;
d = d + 0.01;
```

Could anyone tell me how to get 36.02 as the result ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the problem domain? You could be looking at Math.Round or switching types to System.Decimal, for example.

Comment: I hope you are not getting `36.029999`.  Look again, perhaps it is `36.0199999`?

Comment: You are right i have changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double` is double-precision floating number, `decimal` has more precision.

You should use `decimal` instead of.

```
decimal d = 36.01m;
d = d + 0.01m;
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/T18B5c)**.

And of course I recommend you read to  [`What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 6):

Use `Decimal` instead of `Double`. Decimal has higher accuracy and is recommended when, for instance, you're adding dollar amounts.

Here's a good previous SO post that will give you more details:

[decimal vs double! - Which one should I use and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when)

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are adding floating point numbers. 0.01 is the decimal fraction 1/100<sup>th</sup>, which cannot be exactly represented in binary in the available number of bits. Consider using the `decimal` type, or rounding to the desired precision using the appropriate `Math.Round()` overload and rounding style for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `decimal` as suggested. More importantly, you should read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) to understand the underlying problem